# Grails AWS plugin. How to check if the file has been uploaded successfully to S3

Tags: file, grails, amazon-s3, error-handling, upload

I'm using Grails AWS plugin `org.grails.plugins:grails-aws:2.0.3` and upload file using the `inputStreamUpload` dynamic method on `InputStream`, such as:

```
InputStream is = someInputStream
S3File s3File = is.s3upload(pathName)
```

Now I need to handle file upload errors and the problem is that I can't find anywhere whether the `s3upload` method, in case of unsuccessful upload, throws any exception or returns null or even returns an object with something inside telling us that the file upload has been failed.

I have checked the plugin documentation and the source code but there is no any info.